# alternative to cdi, seam 3, and primefaces 3

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, cdi, seam3

I've been developing JSF applications for quite some time. And some 3 or 4 years ago I discovered seam 2 and it was great. Now I decided to try jsf 2 + cdi + seam 3 + primefaces 3 (I know this version is not final yet) and had so many problems along the way, that I am looking for alternatives.

So, if someone can point me to a framework that adds to jsf 2, can work well with facelets and some component library on top of jsf 2 that is html 5 ready, I'd appreciate it.

Also, I am not discarding leaving jsf 2 behind, so if there is some better alternative I am willing to try.

It really just has to play well with Java EE 6 stack, ejb 3.x, ...

Comment: As far as I know, there are no JSF2 component libraries that support HTML5 yet.  As far as cdi and seam goes they are just plain awful to work with.  Believe it or not it is possible to integrate JSF2 with Spring 3 and then leave the rest of the EE stack in the past where it belongs.  If you were considering alternatives to JSF2 even I hear that people are doing some pretty cool things with Wicket, but personally I haven't run into any problems with Primefaces and JSF that I wasn't able to work around.

Comment: why -1? I think this is a good question. I've seen a lot of people struggling with seam 3 after having a good experience with seam 2...

Comment: @maple_shaft sorry, but I don't agree. Java EE also contains EJB and JPA, which work absolutely great in combination with JSF. There is zero need to "leave that in the past", since these are very modern technologies that are actively and openly being improved all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seam 2 is still being developed and supported. [Seam 2.3.0 will have JSF2 support](http://community.jboss.org/blogs/marek-novotny/2011/12/04/seam-230-in-progress). You can try the alpha release [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jboss/files/JBoss%20Seam/2.3.0.ALPHA), and upgrade (easy with maven) as soon as there is a stable release.

I also tried Seam 3 for a while, but there are a lot of nice things in seam 2 which aren't there (yet?) in Seam 3. So I switched back to Seam 2...